# ServerSocket don't receiving SendText in my Server application

Tags: sockets, delphi, delphi-7

I'm wanting send a file to client application (remote pc) using sockets, but ClientSocket don't receives SendText messages when I send for example as following:

```
ClientSocket3.Socket.SendText('<|sobe|>');
```

for ClientSocket3Read.

CLIENT SIDE =>

```
var
  tamanho: Integer;
  nome: string;
  recebendo: boolean;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;

//==================================================

procedure TForm1.ClientSocket2Error(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent; var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
  ErrorCode := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.ClientSocket2Read(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  dados: String;
begin
  dados := Socket.ReceiveText;

  if Copy(dados,1,6)='<|up|>' then
  Begin
    Delete(dados, 1, 6) ; // Getting only complete path with file name as example C:\file.txt from OpenDialog1 component in my Server application.
    Edit1.Text:= dados; // Receives as for example 'C:\file.txt' :D
    nome:= dados;      // // Receives as for example 'C:\file.txt' :D
    button1.Click;      // Calling button click for SendText('<|sobe|'); for ClientSocket3
    exit;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientSocket3.Socket.SendText('<|sobe|>');
end;

procedure TForm1.ClientSocket3Read(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := Socket.ReceiveText;

  // Testing with warning message, but don't receives '<|sobe|' text in: s := Socket.ReceiveText; and don't execute this line. 

  // Then here begins my trouble :(

  Application.MessageBox(pchar(s), 'Aviso', 64);

  //================================================================================

  if Recebendo = False then begin
    if Pos(#0, s)>0 then begin
      Tamanho := StrToInt(Copy(s, 1, Pos(#0, s)-1));
      Delete(s, 1, Pos(#0, s));
      Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      Pb1.Max := tamanho; // PB1 <= ProgressBar1
      Recebendo := true;
    end;
  end;
  try
    Stream.Write(s[1], Length(s));
    PB1.Position := Stream.Size;

    if Stream.Size >= Tamanho then begin
      Stream.Position := 0;

      if nome = edit1.Text then begin
        Stream.SaveToFile(nome);
        Application.MessageBox('Salvo com sucesso!', 'Aviso', 64);
      end;
      Recebendo := false;
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  except
    Stream.Free;
    Recebendo := false;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ClientSocket3Error(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent; var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
  ErrorCode := 0;
end;
```

In my Server application I send a file as:

SERVER SIDE =>

```
type
  TServ_Sock3 = class(TThread)
    private
      procedure Execute; override;
    public
      Socket: TCustomWinSocket;
end;

    procedure TForm1.EnviarArquivo1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      caminho: String;
    begin
      If not Assigned(LV.Selected) then exit;
      if LV.Selected.Checked = false then exit;

      if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
        caminho := opendialog1.FileName;  // 'C:\file.txt'

        ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[Form1.LV.ItemIndex].SendText('<|up|>'+caminho);

        // PS: LV, is a ListView component that show me all connected computers in my network.

      end;
    end;

procedure TServ_Sock3.Execute;
var
  s: String;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  inherited;

  while not Terminated and Socket.Connected do begin
    if Socket.ReceiveLength>0 then begin
      s := Socket.ReceiveText;

      if Pos('<|sobe|>', s)>0 then begin

          Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;

           Stream.LoadFromFile(caminho);

          Stream.Position := 0;
          Socket.SendText(IntToStr(Stream.Size)+#0);
          Sleep(1000);
          Socket.SendStream(Stream);
        end;
      end;

    end;
    Sleep(10);
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket2ClientError(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
  var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
ErrorCode:=0
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket2Accept(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  Conex: TServ_Sock3;
begin
  Conex := TServ_Sock3.Create(true);
  Conex.Socket := Socket;
  Conex.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  Conex.Resume;

end;
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: You are calling `ClientSocket3.Socket.SendText('<|sobe|>')` to send text to some server. Why are you expecting `ClientSocket3Read()` to receive that text? A client does not receive data that it sends.  It receives data that the server sends. Where is the server code that receives and processes the `'<|sobe|>'` string? You did not show that code. And why do you have two client sockets in the first place?

Comment: For that matter, you should not be using `SendText()` and `ReceiveText()` at all. Especially since you are ignoring their return values, and how they actually work. In TCP, there is no 1-to-1 relationship between a send and a receive, like you code is assuming. TCP is a byte stream, it has no concept of message boundaries. You need to design a real protocol with your own explicit boundaries between messages (whether that be a preceding message length, or a trailing unique delimiter), and you need to be looking for those boundaries when reading data so you don't process data incorrectly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you very much for your answer. I edited my question with the part that ServerSocket (in this case I used the TThread class) receives `<|sobe|>` string  in server side. I have this same algorithm in other application and it works fine there. The ServerSocket on `TServ_Sock3.Execute` procedure, sends a Stream containg the file that I want upload. The ClientSocket2 on Client part receives `<|up|>` string and works fine this part.